# Can two hosts have the same IP address in /etc/hosts?

Tags: networking, dns, hostname, hosts

can two hosts share the same IP Address without a conflict. This is how my /etc/hosts looks like :-

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   debian
127.0.1.1       mini
```

Now as can be seen both mini and debian share the same IP Address.

Now debian is my hostname.

```
$ hostname
debian
```

while mini is a virtual host for an apache site.

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available$ head minidebconfindia.conf 
<VirtualHost mini:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
```

This is in Apache 2.4. I am just not sure whether this is good or not. A friend of mine has the same setup (with a different hostname) on Apache 2.2 and that works without issue.

Looking forward to know if this is valid or should I be doing any changes ?

Answer (score 9):

This fully valid and correctly. Also you can write names in one string with space delimiter:

```
127.0.1.1   debian  mini  mini.local
```

The both variants is fully valid.

Answer (score 1):

> can two hosts share the same IP Address without a conflict
>   Short answer: No.
>
> Now as can be seen both mini and debian share the same IP Address. 
>   No, it's the other way round: Both names resolve to the same IP and *that* is OK.

The IP 127.... are loopback Adresses, only available on your machine, read up [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback).
Note that these IPs are not accessible from outside your computer.

After some deeper research, describe your issue with apache in a new question.

Comment: 127.0.0.0/8 is loopback; private addresses by RFC 1918 are 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/16 and 192.168.0.0/16.

Comment: OMFG, corrected - should get more coffee before posting! Thank you @countermode